# My Font Awesome icon won't show up, and breaks my page's structure

Tags: html, icons, font-awesome, embed

I'm trying to use the following Font Awesome icon

```
<i class="far fa-angle-right"></i>
```

but the icon won't show up.

I tried two different embed codes to insert in my `<head>` section: the first was

```
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and the second one was

```
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/0fa476ae4d.js"></script>
```

Both of them didn't work, and only a null sign appeared instead of my icon. The second embed code also completely broke and messed up my page's structure, pushing my form down.

That's the part where I'm trying to use the icon:

```
<form id="email-form">
        <input
          type="email"
          name="email-input"
          id="email-input"
          placeholder="Email Address"
        />
        <button type="submit" name="submit-button" id="submit-button">
          <i class="far fa-angle-right"></i>
        </button>
</form>
```

Comment: use "fa" instead of "far"
<i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i>

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use fontawesome in your entire project, you can install it globally or define it as "cdn" under index.html page. There may be a more logical solution.

Answer (score 0):

First of all i used link i sen t you above and obtain my own kit. Then i try to use your icon and it works. 
and taht icon should be

```
<i class="fas fa-angle-right"></i>
```

and not

```
<i class="far fa-angle-right"></i>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you look up the [angle-right](https://fontawesome.com/icons/angle-right?style=solid) Icon in their [directory](https://fontawesome.com/icons), you'll see that it requires a Pro-licence. If you don't have one, you have to use the `s`-style. The "null-icon" you mentioned is the usual flag to indicate missing/invalid icon.

[image]